# Does an iOS app use battery when in the background or when the device is locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, optimization

I am working on an iOS project where the gyro and accelerometer is always on, has animations running as well as a timer.

What actually happens to the app on iOS 7 - iOS 10 when switching apps and the app is relegated to the background or when the device is locked -- does the gyro and accelerometer, running animations and timers automatically pause and turn off?

Should I expect when an app is relegated to the background or when the device is locked, the app stops drawing battery?

Or should I manually pause or turn off the gyro and accelerometer, running animations and timers when `applicationDidEnterBackground` is triggered and then recommence everything when `applicationDidEnterForeground` is triggered?

Comment: Have you enabled background mode capability?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "background mode capability"? At the moment, I can switch apps or lock the device and then when coming back to the app, everything seems to be running. The app does restart if many apps have been launched.

Comment: You can check it experimentally. Just run your app, put it into background for a day, then go to Settings > Battery and check BATTERY USAGE table.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will stop, and without enabled specific background mode like location updates or Background Fetching it won't return to "run" until it will be in the foreground

The NSTimes will stop also.
I think it's better practice to update the state in the applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationDidEnterForeground

Answer (score 1):

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to know about background execution.

By default, when your app goes to background state then it's not performing any task.

You have to made setup for continue execution in background mode. And that have `limitations` also like you can not perform everything or anything that you want. You have limitations like, `finite length task,location update,background music play, downloading, voip` etc..! You can know more from above link.

So, if you have configured anything that's capable to works continue in background, then your app will consumes battery in background otherwise not.

`Apple allows only some kind of tasks in background, and one major reason is long battery life !!!!`

Comment: My aim is to halt all processes like the gyro and accelerometer, running animations and timers when the app is in the background or device is locked. I don't believe I've set up any background execution.

Comment: Then your default behavior should be like as you expect!!  Then i don't think that you need to do any additional thing to do so!!